# Having trouble bulk editing link titles in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, hyperlink, quick-edit

I want to bulk edit the "display this text" field for a column of hyperlinks in Sharepoint Online and 2013. Even better, I'd like for it to default to a word so that the user only has to enter the link (this is secondary to my inquiry here, so if too complex, no worries).

For the online version, I've tried selecting multiple list items and choosing "info" icon in the upper right of the page to "bulk edit properties". But "Alternative text" shows and not the main field.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint 2013, when you edit hyperlinks column, it shows as display text.
[image]

In the SharePoint Online, when you edit hyperlinks column, it shows as Alternative text.
[image]

These two mean the same.

Comment: Thanks, Emily. I was hoping that was the case, but Alternative Text is for visually impaired users. It seems to me that these two fields are not the same as my changes to that field did not change the Display text. Is there another way to make this change in bulk?